# How to select elements from a handelbars template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, dom, handlebars.js

We have a div within our webpage:

```
<div id="person-details">
    <div></div>
    ...
</div>
```

We select the relevant elements from this div using the following jQuery code:

```
var person = $("#person-details");
var children = release.find("div");
var fullname = children.first();
```

We use a render function to perform an ajax request to get a handlebars template that we're storing in an external file:

```
function _render() {
    var templateScript;
    template.getTemplate(filename).done(function(template) {
        templateScript = Handlebars.compile(template);
        fullname.html(templateScript(context));
    });
}
```

The template looks like the following:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <p>{{name}}</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>{{value}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

After the render function has been called, we want to select any of the elements from within the template. For example we have tried using:

`fullname.children('div');`

but as the content has been dynamically generated we aren't able to get the nodes from within the DOM.

Is it even possible to select elements from within a generated handlebars template like this?

Comment: It is possible, just remember that javascript will execute asynchronously, so you may be selecting a DOM element that is yet to be rendered.

Comment: @DanielShillcock Thanks Daniel, completely overlooked the async nature of render.

Comment: Here is a snippet that may help. Every input is printed to console. http://codepen.io/IronAces/pen/NAEOWy?editors=101#anon-login

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @DanielShillcock for highlighting `render()` being asynchronous. Here is a solution:

```
function _render() {
    var templateScript;
    template.getTemplate(filename).done(function(template) {
        templateScript = Handlebars.compile(template);
        selector.html(templateScript(attribute));
        value = selector.find("div");
    });
}
```